# Nokogiri: Find first occurence of a node without class attribute

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

In the following snippet, I would like to get the first occurrence of <b> tag without a class attribute.

```html
<html>
<body>
     <p>This is the <b class="abc">text in bold with a class attribute</b> and the following is <b> text in bold without a class attribute</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7):

That would be:

```
doc.at('b:not([class])')
```